# Haskell where clause: is it more than just a matter of taste?

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, scheme, pascal

The traditional (Scheme, Pascal) way to structure code is this:

```
declare outer function
  declare inner function
    body of inner function
  body of outer function
```

The `where` clause in Haskell moves the inner function from the beginning to the end.

```
declare outer function
  body outer function
  where
    declare inner function
      body of inner function
```

I would say the tradional way is bottom-up: the source code begins with the code executed last. While the second way is top-down: the source begins with the code executed first.

Are the two ways to write code equivalent and just a matter of taste, or are there (from the software engineering point of view) differences, which are significant?

Comment: A Haskell function is one expression, so the first form isn't valid Haskell, and iirc "executed first" isn't meaningful either

Comment: Declaration before use is required if you have a single pass compiler

Comment: @Caleth: yes, the first form is not how Haskell programs are structured - exactly what the OP wrote. And your second comment looks like a good start for an answer.

Comment: You can do either - `let..in` for subfunctions first, `where` for subfunctions last.

Comment: @SebastianRedl found it: https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where